# JQuery accordion not initializing in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a bunch of JQuery accordions on a page, all with class "accordion", and I want to initialize them. I know I can do this:

```
var accordions = $( ".accordion" );
accordions.accordion();
```

However, I need to initialize them all with slightly different parameters based on their attributes. So I try the following code:

```
var accordions = $( ".accordion" );        
for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++)
{
    var autoExpand = accordions[i].getAttribute("autoExpand"); // get attribute            
    accordions[i].accordion({ 
            animate: 100, 
            active: location.href.includes(autoExpand) ? 0 : false, 
            collapsible: true, 
            heightStyle: "content",
            icons: { header: "ui-icon-plus", activeHeader: "ui-icon-minus" } 
       });  
}
```

But I get this error:
**jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: accordions[i].accordion is not a function**

Why is this happening?

Comment: Without loop accordion is  working or not?

Comment: Have you included jquery ui reference in your document?

Comment: Yeah, accordions.accordion(); works, but I get the error message in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this, and set the condition using incremental value of `i` or you can increase the parameters in function

```
function setAcc(a,i){
$(a).accordion({ 
            animate: 100, 
            active: location.href.includes(autoExpand) ? 0 : false, 
            collapsible: true, 
            heightStyle: "content",
            icons: { header: "ui-icon-plus", activeHeader: "ui-icon-minus" } 
       });  

}

var accordions = $( ".accordion" );        
for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++)
{

 setAcc(accordions,i);   

}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why I have to do it this way, but your solution worked. Thanks Kamlesh